# Show bootstrap modal only if URL has certain parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way using Bootstrap's modal functionality to evaluate the URL for parameters and open the modal automatically?

For example:

Visitors to the site with URL : `example.com` don't see the modal. They just see the regular site.

Visitors to the site with URL `example.com?offer=1234` or `example.com/offer1234` see the regular `example.com` site, but with a special modal over the top when the page loads.

Can't figure out any way to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, of course this is possible by only running some JavaScript code if the query string (offer=1234) or URL (/offer1234) matched.

Insert this javascript code somewhere after the div where your modal is declared, typically best to add just before your ending `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('?offer=1234') != -1 || url.IndexOf('/offer1234') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

You can tweak the if statement however you like, exclude only one statement either side of the double pipe symbols `||` (OR) if you only want to test one of those url patterns, and where `myModal` defines a div with your modal content to display (eg. `<div id="myModal"></div>`).

See the documentation for more options and guidelines.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

**Update I have also put together a working Plunker for you demonstrating:
http://run.plnkr.co/yEBML6nxvxKDf0YC/?offer=1234**

Comment: Can this actually work with `example.com/offer`? Won't this try to find a directory?

Comment: I have updated with some demo code. It won't, if all this code is installed into offer1234.html or that path resolves to some html somehow, I'm not familiar with your setup.

Comment: Your plnkr didn't open a modal for me. I can't get your code to work on my site either.

Comment: Sorry run it again. You caught me during a final edit :)

Comment: Okay. Plnkr worked that time. I was really hoping to have this on my main page, which uses `index.html`, but resolves to `example.com`. Is there a way to set this up such that `example.com/offer` actually points to this page with the modal (without redirects)?

Comment: Research url rewriting, are you using any server side technologies such as asp.net? That's really a separate topic you will have to research, but is possible through server-side techniques, if `offer` doesn't exist as a true html file.

Comment: So basically have `example.com/offer` redirect to something like `example.com/?offer=1234`? I guess I could do a rewrite rule, but that might be a little bit much for this little task I need it for. Got it working using `?=` and that should be good enough for now. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I got this all working with a rewriterule, so your code above saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the URL if it has "offer" or not to hide/show the modal

```
var hasParam = window.location.href.indexOf('offer');

if(hasParam) {
   $('#aModal').show();
} else {
  $('#aModal').hide();
}

<div id="aModal" class="modal"> </div>
```

Comment: What would the URL structure have to look like for this to work. I tried `example.com?offer=1234` and that didn't work.

Comment: @IsabelHM The div will have to be declared above the js code and obviously wrapped in script tags but that's a given.

Comment: This simply isn't working for me even with the div before the script.

Comment: @GONeale This is basically the same answer as yours. Nope. not writing the entire running code 'cause I assume jonmrich has a basic understanding on how to implement basics (unless I'm wrong) and just need a second thought on how to do it. cheers.