# Bootstrap modal popup for login

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal popup for login, I need to know how to  display the error message on the same popup which is coming from a controller action in mvc 5.

Please any suggestion.

Comment: Need to change title

Answer (score 4):

***Define the empty modal div on the HTML page***

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class='modal-oem-error''>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='element'>Show Modal Data On Ajax</button>
```

***In controller your code looks like:-***

```
def login
   # login code
    status ? (render :partial=>'after_login_template') : (render :json=>{status:'false' , value_data: @instance.errors.full_messages.join('|')})
  end
```

***Script to send request on click of button , fetch data from server and display in modal.***

```
$('#element').on('click', function () {
  $j.ajax({
   url: '/localhost/resource',
   type: "POST",
   data: {id:123}
   }).done(function (data) {
      if (data.status == 'false') {
          $j('.modal-oem-error').show();
           array = data.value_data.split('|')
                         $j.each(array, function (i) {
                             $j('.modal-oem-error').append('<p>' + array[i] + '</p>')
                         });
                       } else {
                        $j('#myModal').modal('hide')
                        $j('#list).html(data)
                        $j('.modal-oem-error').html('');
                        $j('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    }
                });
});
```

---

***If needed on close of modal we can empty the modal div***

---

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
 $('#myModal').html('');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make use of URL structure to show that modal.
Here is a question addressing just that: [Show Modal from Custom URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079380/show-bootstrap-modal-only-if-url-has-certain-parameters). Check the accepted answer. (Credits to the original author).

Basically, you need to add javascript to check the last piece of the URL, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('?error=123') != -1 || url.IndexOf('/error123') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

Then, you can route your model error response to login/*error123*

Answer (score 1):

You need to write just one line in your js

```
toastr.success('YOUR MESSAGE');
```

Comment: you can keep danger or else insteade of success for diffrent type of messages

Answer (score 0):

Do JavaScript validation on modal before you submit, disable submit if validation fails.

**Update:**
Since there is no code to work with Ill leave logic to you.

1. Do validation
2. Showmodal if validation fails set a variable in viewbag to show modal again using razor(i don't think this is best practise )

   ```
     if('@ViewBag.IsLegit' !== 'True')
     {
          //showModal
     }
   ```

Comment: I cannot do that with JS since the logic and call to DB is in controller action..need to return to the modal after validation..any example please.. Thanks!

Comment: So the validation is in the action method. This doesn't seem right. If your modal acts like a form make it a form or validate with ajax requests. I will update my answer with a basic example

Comment: I have to use controller action since I need to access database to check email/password validity, not only syntax verification...Thanks!

Comment: Yes I am using form inside modal

Comment: After validation the modal displays error in window but the login button does not work

Comment: @Suhel it is very difficult to help you without code, does your console respond with any errors?