# Show bootstrap modal when url has some parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to develop web apps, I'm creating a mini project which has a simple signup, signing system, I don't want user to go to a different page to login, instead I have used a [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) which has a login form for which I have a button that on click also changes the url and also triggers the modal. Now I only want to show the modal, if url has parameter = `?action=login`.

Firstly, I have tried `document.getElementById('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', setQry)` to my button which calls the function which on click changes the url parameter. The url parameter changes on click really fine, but the modal does not show up, please note that I have `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes on my button for the modal to show. I have also tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079380/show-bootstrap-modal-only-if-url-has-certain-parameters). But its not working.

I just want to achieve that modal should show up, if url has the parameter
and on login success I want to hide the modal and also delete the url parameter.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<button type='button' id='toggle-modal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#login-modal'></button>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('#toggle-modal').addEventListener('click', setQry);
function setQry() {
    const url = new URL('http://localhost/learning%20php/practice%20programs/login%20system/');
    var qry_params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    if (!qry_params.has('action', 'login')) {
        qry_params.set('action', 'login');
        window.location.search = qry_params;
    }
    if (window.location.search == qry_params) {
        $('#login-modal').modal('show');
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry, i ihave typo at url parameter ?action=login.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Manuel.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, your handler only fires on click, it doesn't have effect on page load, for this reason, it should be called to handle parameters on a page loading, sorry for my bad english

```js
setQry();

function setQry() {
    const url = new URL('http://localhost/learning%20php/practice%20programs/login%20system/');
    var qry_params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    if (!qry_params.has('action', 'login')) {
        qry_params.set('action', 'login');
        window.location.search = qry_params;
    }
    if (window.location.search == qry_params) {
        $('#login-modal').modal('show');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PHP for that. You can get the GET Params in PHP and then change the content dependent on the get parameters.

```
<?php

if ($_GET['action'] == "login")
{

?> 

<!-- Add content in html if action code is set to "login" --> 

<?php

}

else
{ 
....

} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The event is called twice when the button is clicked. so I have remove other attributes from button. 
   `<button type='button' id='toggle-modal' ></button>`
2. the `#` used in `document.getElementById('#toggle-modal').addEventListener('click', setQry);` is also creating the issue.
3. setting parameters in javascript `qry_params.set('action', 'login');` is refreshing the page. so the popup gets close.

so the update code is given below hope it will resolve the issue
``'`

```
<button type='button' id='toggle-modal' ></button>


<script>
document.getElementById('toggle-modal').addEventListener('click', setQry);
function setQry() {

const url = new URL('http://localhost/learning%20php/practice%20programs/login%20system/?action=login');
var qry_params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
if (window.location.search.replace("?", "") == qry_params) {
        $('#login-modal').modal('show');
    }

}; </script>
```

Comment: have you added `?action=login` in your browser url ?

Comment: finally it is working but in a weird way, modal gets activated on the second click. it will be really great if you can figure out the problem of second click, here's my code  function setQry()
      {
        var url = window.location.href.toString();
        var qry_str = '?action=login';
        if (url.endsWith(qry_str) == false) 
        {
          window.location.search = qry_str;
        }
        if (window.location.search == qry_str)
          {
            $('#login-modal').modal('show');
          }
      }

Comment: I checked your code, first click set query string in browser url and second click popups. so if you remove `if (url.endsWith(qry_str) == false) { 
    window.location.search = qry_str; } ` and use `?action=login` in browser url it will work as you expect.

Comment: Try this code it will resolve your issue 

function setQry() { 
  var url = window.location.href.toString(); 
  var qry_str = '?action=login'; 

   if (url.endsWith(qry_str) == false) { 
  
      if (window.history.pushState) { 
        const newURL = new URL(window.location.href); 
        newURL.search = '?action=login'; 
        window.history.pushState({ path: newURL.href }, '', newURL.href); }
         } 


    if (window.location.search == qry_str) { 
      $('#login-modal').modal('show'); }

       }